# Cannot access class constant from an instance using the :: scope operator

Tags: php

I hit a strange problem today and even as a PHP engineer i'm stumped at this:

It seems you can access a class constant from an object instance such as:

```
class a {
    const abc = 1;
}
$a = new a();
var_dump($a->abc);
```

This will output null instead of the expected 1. I was able to do the following:

```
class a {
    const abc = 1;
}
$a = new a();
var_dump(a::abc);
```

But in the context of a sub object that doesn't really know who the parent is exactly, i find it extremely annoying to do:

```
class a {
    const abc = 1;
}
$a = new a();
$c = get_class($a);
var_dump($c::abc);
```

Is it me or this is completly stupid, if not, please enlighten me why its working that way.

**EDIT**

Another way of doing it but it's not really better:

```
class a {
    const abc = 1;
}
class b {
    public function getA(){
        return new a();
    }
}
$b = new b();
$c = $b->getA();
var_dump($c::abc);
```

This last example works more like what i am doing and experiencing...

Comment: Are constants automatically `static`?

Comment: In php, constants are tied to the class definition, they are static by definition and cannot be accessed using the -> operator. Sadly, that happens to be the nature of the beast..

Comment: You can use the `self::` instead of `$this->` to get access to the class constants. In your case you can just make ``$a = new A(); var_dump(a::abc);``

Comment: You are missing the point, i wanted to use static dereferencing which doesn't exist yet!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a relatively nice and clean way to make my problem easier to live with. Here is the solution i've applied. It is not necessarely the best but for my uses it does exactly what i need.

By creating a magic __get method, i intercept the request for the constant name from and instance point of view and i use a quick reflection to see if that constant exists and return it's value.

This allows me to actually use all in one line a pattern that looks like this:

```
class a {
    const abc = 1;
    public function __get($key){
        $r = new ReflectionObject($this);
        if($r->hasConstant($key)){ return $r->getConstant($key); }
    }
}
class b {
    public function getA(){
        return new a();
    }
}
$b = new b();
var_dump($b->getA()->abc);
var_dump($b->getA()->def);
```

Althought i'd have liked to do:

```
var_dump($b->getA()::abc);
var_dump($b->getA()::def);
```

I guess this could be possible later in 5.4+ considering we finaly have array dereferencing, we could probably ask them to add static dereferencing soon.

Answer (score 17):

Just use the instance variable with the scope resolution operator:

```
$a = new a();
var_dump($a::abc);
```

This [prints](http://viper-7.com/ekGT1i) `1`.

Comment: Is this supported before PHP 5.3?

Comment: Thats what i'm forced to do, but it's a bit ugly, i'd like to do it like $a->getB()::abc. but it's not supported...

Comment: @arxanas - From my test, no, you get my absolute favorite error message: `unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`.

Comment: In PHP 5.6 it works. However only in unnested instances. e.g. `$b->a = $a; var_dump($b->a::abc);` does not work!

Comment: @flori it works since PHP 5.3 (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Comment: @flori Nice to see someone else confirm this, I thought I was going mad.  The only workaround I've found is `$b->a = $a; $c = $b->a; var_dump($c::abc);` which is less than ideal IMO

Comment: @Londeren:  `$this->someObject::CONST`  definitely doesn't work and the manual doesn't address this.

Comment: Using -> and :: in same expression sometimes doesn't work, something to do with uniform variable syntax. I'm too lazy to link you to anything but you can look it up yourself. Later versions of php address it I think. In my experience, I just know to avoid it most of the time, which sucks.

Answer (score 5):

[The PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) indicates that class constants are accessed via SRO (`::`) rather than `->`.

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const constant = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::constant . "\n";
    }
}

echo MyClass::constant . "\n";
```

Comment: Why are you just pasting what i already wrote about, i know that it should be done this way, what i want is to find a better way. You're not really helping

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin *"Is it me or this is completly stupid, if not, please enlighten me why its working that way.*" I thought I was enlightening you.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin It's like asking "why can't I use `=` for comparison?" Because that's not what `=` is used for.

Comment: With function calls we can use array dereferencing in PHP 5.4, why couldn't we use class dereferencing from function calls, thats beyond me. (Note i don't know if thats the rigth term, but thats what i'd like)

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I don't think it's a matter of dereferencing. Class `constants` are `static` by nature, therefore they have to be accessed as static.

Comment: Exactly, but why can we do $a::abc but not $b->getA()::abc thats the annoying part, thats what i mean by deferencing

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Ah. Maybe 5.5 will have class dereferencing. :-/

Answer (score 3):

ike I mentioned, in php constants are tied to the class definition, they are static by definition and cannot be accessed using the -> operator.

If you really want to use it with your coding paradigm, you can try the reflection class in php5.

```
class MyClass
{
   const A = "I am A";
}

$o = new ReflectionClass( "MyClass" );
echo $o->getconstant("A"); //will print "I am A"
```

Also, I think the example in your **EDIT** might not work..I did not run it, but I am not sure if the SRO(::) can be invoked on anything that is not a class reference..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but for people who want to know the best way to do this have a look at the PHP function [constant()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

With constant() you can simply do this:

```
$a = new a();
$value = constant(get_class($a)."::abc");
// $value === 1
```

this has been available since PHP 4, and still works perfectly in PHP 5.5

Comment: The problem was to be able to access in a clean way the static constant of a dereferenced object which is not possible. With PHP 5.4 you can now automatically derefence arrays off return functions but you still can't dereference static members off them, you have to create a middle man variable that will then be called. Thats the whole point of the problem i'm afraid!

Comment: In all reality, it seems like the problem was accessing constants from an instanced object, well at least that's what I got from reading the post.

"It seems you can access a class constant from an object instance such as:"

Comment: I might have written it wrong, let me edit the post to make sure it doesn't get anyone else confused

Answer (score -1):

When trying to use `const` defined in a class inside a different namespace, the **Scope Resolution Operator** (`::`) can be used without problems as stated by [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#example-182) prefixing the namespace before the class in which the const was declared with this format:

- `(<namespace>"\")*<className>::<const>`

With the next namespace, class and const definitions:

**models/OperationModel.php**

```php
<?php
namespace models;

class OperationModel {
  const OPERATION_INITIALIZING = 1;
}
```

You can use the const from another namespace\class like this:

**controllers/MobileController.php**

```php
<?php
namespace controllers;

use models\OpertionModel;

class MobileController {
  private function thingy() {
    $operation_status = models\OperationModel::OPERATION_INITIALIZING;
  }
}
```