# Accessing constant of an injected class in PHP

Tags: php, class

```
class A{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 'my constant';
}

class B{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        return $this->a::MY_CONSTANT;
    }

}
```

Why the constant is not accessible like this way - $this->a::MY_CONSTANT? Anybody knows any other ways?

Comment: how are you using B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above can be achieved in this way. Here we are using [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function to get classname as string. which we are storing it in a variable and then retrieve the value of constant by using that variable.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/804800)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class A{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 'my constant';
}

class B{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {

        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $class=get_class($this->a);
        echo $class::MY_CONSTANT;
    }

}
$object=new B(new A());
$object->someFunction();
```

Comment: That works. Thanks @Sahil Gulati. But I was wondering why PHP does not support $this->a::MY_CONSTANT. PHP sucks!!!!!

Comment: @SelimMahmud _PHP doesnot support_  In PHP we can access constants with `classname::constant_name` so here we are getting classname as string and accessing constant

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same by this approach.

```
class A{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 'my constant';
    public function __get($key){
        $r = new ReflectionObject($this);
        if($r->hasConstant($key)){ return $r->getConstant($key); }
    }
}

class B{       
    public function someFunction()
    {
       return new A();
    }    
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b->someFunction()->MY_CONSTANT);
```

[Original Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977125/4198099)